# Issue running NPM update command from Node child_process exec in a gulp task

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, child-process

I'm using a gulp task to build and deploy multiple projects/apps. One of the steps in this task is to run an `npm update` for each app so I'm using a node `child_process exec` statement to run this command in the relevant app working directory:

```
exec('npm update', {cwd:'./appfolder}, function (err) {...});
```

I wasn't getting any problems and it was working fine until one particular npm update was giving the following error (abbreviated with ... for clarity):

```
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "...\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "update"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.4
npm ERR! path ...\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modules\async
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '...\appfolder\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modules\async' -> '....\appfolder\node_modules\gulp-uglify\node_modules\async'
```

Indeed, the `'...\appfolder\node_modules\uglify-js\node_modules\async'` directory did not exist so in desperation I attempted running the `npm update` manually in the command line and strangely this worked!

So why does the npm update being run from the `child_process exec` statement in a gulp task not work? FYI, I'm running the gulp task from the command line which is running as Administrator. Hence I presume that the necessary rights are being transferred from the command line through to gulp through to the `child process exec` through to the `npm update`. Or maybe not!! Oh and this is being run on Windows.

Comment: Do state your version of npm. Whenever that problem emerges, I just remove the whole node_modules folder and try again.

Comment: @E_net4: The versions are mentioned in the error message. It's supposed to be an automated process. If I have to remove the whole node_modules folder then I'll have to do so after attempting an update. And if it fails, then delete folder and run npm install. I did think of this - crazy solution but still curious as to why running the command normally actually works.

Comment: I'm also wondering if a `spawn` would be better than an `exec`.

Comment: `spawn` made no difference. In the end, I had to settle for @E_net4 advice and deleted the node_modules folder and ran `npm install`.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with node v8.7.0 on linux still. Any work arounds yet?